# How do I fetch JSON data with Vue and Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to fetch product data from a JSON file, but can't get it to work.
I've tried several things and searched the internet for a solution but none of the examples on the internet equals my situation.
I'm new to both vue and axios, so please excuse my ignorance.

This is what I have so far:

```
Vue.component('products',{
data: {
    results: []
},
mounted() {
    axios.get("js/prods.json")
    .then(response => {this.results = response.data.results})
},
template:`
<div id="products">
<div class="productsItemContainer" v-for="product in products">
            <div class="productsItem">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="mkcenter" style="position:relative">
                        <a class="item">
                            <img class="productImg" width="120px" height="120px" v-bind:src="'assets/products/' + product.image">
                            <div class="floating ui red label" v-if="product.new">NEW</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="productItemName" >
                    <a>{{ product.name }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mkdivider mkcenter"></div>
                <div class="productItemPrice" >
                    <a>€ {{ product.unit_price }}</a>
                </div>
                <div v-on:click="addToCart" class="mkcenter">
                    <div class="ui vertical animated basic button" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="hidden content">Koop</div>
                        <div class="visible content">
                            <i class="shop icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
new Vue({
el:"#app",
});
```

The json file is as follows

```
{
    "products":[
        {
            "name": "Danser Skydancer",
            "inventory": 5,
            "unit_price": 45.99,
            "image":"a.jpg",
            "new":true
        },
        {
            "name": "Avocado Zwem Ring",
            "inventory": 10,
            "unit_price": 123.75,
            "image":"b.jpg",
            "new":false
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is only with the fetching of the data from a JSON file, because the following worked:

```
Vue.component('products',{
    data:function(){
        return{
            reactive:true,
            products: [
           {
            name: "Danser Skydancer",
            inventory: 5,
            unit_price: 45.99,
            image:"a.jpg",
            new:true
          },
          {
            name: "Avocado Zwem Ring",
            inventory: 10,
            unit_price: 123.75,
            image:"b.jpg",
            new:false
          }
            ],
          cart:0
        }
    },
   template: etc.........
```

Comment: What do you see in the console? Also, you will want to `v-for` the `results` rather than `products`, unless that is a typo...

Comment: The console shows the following:
vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

Comment: and<br>
vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Products>
       <Root>

Comment: Are you running Vue with CDN?

Comment: No I downloaded it. Both Vue and Axios work properly. The problem isnt with the files. The following displays the correct data in the console `axios.get('/js/products.json')
  .then(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });`

Comment: First of all, please change your array name from `results` to `products` and make the `data` part a function returning the objects/data.

Comment: I changed t=rsult to products, but do not get your 2nd suggestion. How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warnings suggest, please do the following:

1. Rename the data array from `results` to `products` since you are referencing it by the latter one as a name during render.
2. Make your data option a function returning an object since data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object. Have a look at [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) on this.

```js
Vue.component('products', {
  data() {
    return {
      products: []
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("js/prods.json")
      .then(response => {
        this.products = response.data.products;
      });
  },

  template: `
    //...
  `
}
```

```vue
<div id="products">
  <div class="productsItemContainer" v-for="product in products">
    <div class="productsItem">
 ...
```

Also, since you're not using CDN (I think), I would suggest making the template a component with a separate Vue file rather than doing it inside template literals, something like that:

#### Products.vue

```vue
<template>
  <div id="products">
    <div class="productsItemContainer" v-for="product in products">
      <div class="productsItem">
        <!-- The rest of the elements -->
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Products',
    
    data() {
      return {
        products: []
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      axios
        .get("js/prods.json")
        .then(response => {
          this.products = response.data.products;
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

And then in your main JS file or anywhere else requiring this component:

```vue
import Products from './components/Products.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data() {
    return {
      //...
    }
  },
  
  components: {
    Products
  }
})
```

```vue
<div id="app">

  <Products />

</div>
```